# If I no longer control a permanent when it would be sacrificed, is it still sacrificed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I control [Planar Chaos](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlanar%20Chaos%5d) and in response to its ability give it away with [Zedruu the Greathearted](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZedruu%20the%20Greathearted%5d)'s ability, will Planar Chaos still be sacrificed if I lose the coin flip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190503.txt) say:

> 701.16a To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, **or something that’s a permanent they don’t control.** Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.

(emphasis mine)

So in that case, your opponent will control Planar Chaos and it won't be sacrificed.

Comment: Worth clarifying that you cannot activate Zedruu's ability during the resolution, so you would have to use his ability before you flip. You can't do it in response to losing the flip.